# A lot of mistakes in xiosbase file. Even Hello World doesn't run. C++

Tags: c++

I was writing a small program in C++ to translate infix notation to polish notation and RPN, but after running it a ton of mistakes popped up in xiosbase file. I tried to run a simpler code but xiosbase mistakes are still there.I am just starting to code and I have no idea how header files work (and any other file except the one I am writing).
This is Hello World.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and here are all the mistakes I get:

[image: https://s13.postimg.org/5lb9954fb/Untitled.png]

Keep in mind that I am a massive newbie

Comment: Looks like you compiler installation is hosed.  I would uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: It's OT, but you can also [avoid `system("pause");`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).